# Neural Network Layer for Binary Outputs

Tags: neural-networks, binary-data, lstm, softmax, pybrain

I'm currently using an LSTM network to make a yes or no decision in a robot.  The network has a single output with the values in training data being 0 for one decision and 1 for another.  The problem is, I have to decide a threshold value between 0 and 1 for deciding what registers a yes and what registers a no.  This requires some tuning.  I thought if the result was rounded before being passed as the output this could help move the optimal threshold to .5 during training, however, I'm not sure if this would work, or if it has been done before (currently I'm using Pybrain for quick development so making this myself would slow down my project considerably).

I also thought it might be worth splitting the output into 2 nodes, one for yes and one for no.  Then adding a softmax layer- but I'm not sure if that's the best solution either.

I'm training with RPropMinus

Answer (score 2):

## Cross-entropy loss doesn't threshold anything

The loss is the loss. That's fine -- we'd like loss functions to be differentiable because that's how backprop works.

## Your choice of threshold depends on your goals, full stop.

Lots of real-world problems have different costs for different kinds of errors. If you're a doctor and you have a diagnostic test, a false positive could have consequences from the trivial (prescribing a unnecessary antibiotics) to severe (unnecessary invasive surgery). Recent work on self-driving cars gives us another example: failing to detect a bicyclist or pedestrian in the path of the vehicle could kill a person.

In a medical context, doctors take the results of a test as additional information to consider in the context of the rest of the patient's medical status and their circumstances. In that sense, doctors don't really ever apply a "cutoff" to their decision-making.

When designing automatic systems, we don't have the luxury of expert intervention for all actions. So instead of picking 0.5 arbitrarily, it's usually more worthwhile to consider context. What are the costs of each kind of error? What's a reasonable trade-off? I can't answer this question for you -- nor would you want me to, since if I pick the wrong value, I don't face any consequences!

## If the relative cost for errors are equal, thresholding at a value that minimizes total errors is fine.

Comment: In my specific case I'm equally concerned about false positives and false negatives, and I hope to minimize the number of all errors rather than either one in particular.  I will be generating/training the networks and thresholds automatically in the future and that's why I am looking for a solution to this problem.  Perhaps I should add that to the question

Comment: If the relative cost for errors are equal, thresholding at a value that minimizes total errors is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the threshold does not matter during training as your objective function is the binary cross entropy (usually).

It is common to use 0.5 as a threshold for validation, for balanced classes. If they are not balanced, you should try to make it so as 0.5 would not give you sensible results.

Comment: I would recommend changing the threshold instead of mutilating the data.